# How can I extract and use images from an archive in a Jasper report?

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports, ireport

I need to put images in my Jasper reports that match rows in a database. I have the image data in proprietary archive files which I can easily extract in Java code. I need to know how to connect my Java code to the Jasper report to make the extraction process happen, something like BIRT's **onRowSets()** method. (I need overview documentation about how the fill process works.)

If I define a POJO/bean data source, I won't be able to easily use the database as well. Can I embed the necessary Java extraction code right in the XML? [This example at the Jasper Assistant site](http://www.jasperassistant.com/forum/topic/33/jasper_reports_image_expression?p2) seems to indicate that I can:

```
   <imageExpression class="java.io.File">
      <![CDATA[(new File($P{BaseDir}, "logo_"+$P{ReportCollecter}+".gif").exists()) 
         ? new File($P{BaseDir}, "logo_"+$P{ReportCollecter}+".gif") 
         : new File($P{BaseDir}, "logo_BLANK.gif")]]>
   </imageExpression>
```

Is that **new File()** actually Java code embedded in the XML? I'm willing to write code, but I can't seem to find any complete class code examples (I think I want something like an extended image object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the current version of iReport (3.6.0) uses Groovy (a sort of Java scripting language) which has full access to any Java libraries in your classpath.

All I had to do was write some code to extract the image from the archive and return an InputStream object (from a ByteArrayInputStream). Then I made a jar file and called the function from the Jasper jrxml file like so:

```
<imageExpression class="java.io.InputStream">
   <![CDATA[
com.mycompany.jasper.MyImageExtractor.getImage($F{IMAGE_URL}, $V{JasperVariable})
   ]]>
</imageExpression>
```

(You can also link to your code with the iReport GUI -- set the "Image Expression" property for your new image to the line after the "CDATA")

For simpler Java coding needs, you can [write simple Groovy code](http://www.infoviae.it/jasperreports_e.html) right in the XML of the report.

Note that Jasper variables can be accessed in Groovy with `$V{VariableName}` and SQL Database columns can be accessed with `$F{ColumnName}`.